# Перестал работать PHP

Tags: php, apache

После установки новой темы в wordpress перестал обрабатывать файлы php apache. На сервере ничего не делал, куда смотреть? Windows server 2019
Лог:

```
[Tue Jan 18 09:10:44.514975 2022] [core:warn] [pid 2612:tid 516]    AH00098: pid file C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean    shutdown of previous Apache run? 
[Tue Jan 18 09:10:44.983726 2022]    [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2612:tid 516] AH00455: Apache/2.4.52 (Win64)    OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.0.12 configured -- resuming normal operations    
[Tue Jan 18 09:10:44.983726 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2612:tid    516] AH00456: Server built: Dec 17 2021 15:13:12 
[Tue Jan 18    09:10:44.983726 2022] [core:notice] [pid 2612:tid 516] AH00094:    Command line: 'c:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24' 
[Tue Jan    18 09:10:44.983726 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2612:tid 516]    AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4380 
[Tue Jan 18    09:10:46.905621 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4380:tid 1188] AH00354:    Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: В первую очередь смотреть надо в логи и читать что там написано

Comment: как вы определили, что "перестал обрабатывать"?

Comment: В браузере кажет код страницы

Comment: проверьте конфиг apache. Там должен быть хэндлер обработки php файлов. Также в настройках php посмотрите разрешены ли short_tags

Comment: Все отбой, эта тема записала в корневой каталог файл .htaccess и из за этого php перестал работать, жесть конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Все отбой, эта тема записала в корневой каталог файл .htaccess и из за этого php перестал работать, жесть конечно